# JSON.parse() never finish

Tags: javascript, html, json

any ideas why the following html - blocks forever on JSON.parse(..)
(I'm trying to parse a json response from a IoT server json seems valid but the the parsing is freezes )

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="iot_data_dump"></div>

<script>

var data1 = {
        "thing": 1000,
        "last": [
        {"t": 1541239266580, "r": 96, "d": [ 138, 47, 188, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0] },
        {"t": 1541236276321, "r": 97, "d": [ 140, 49, 187, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0] },
        {"t": 1541236161222, "r": 98, "d": [ 140, 49, 187, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0] }
        ]
        };

function iot_json_function(data) {
        var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
        var out = "Thing: " + json_data.thing + "<br>";
        for (line in json_data.last) {
          out += "&nsbp;Time: " + line.t + "<br>";
          out += "&nsbp;Signal Strength: " + line.r + "<br>";
          out += "&nbsp;Data: "
          for (val in line.d) {
             out += val + " ";
          }
          out += "<br>"
        }
 document.getElementById("iot_data_dump").innerHTML = out;
}

iot_json_function(data1);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not the problem (it could easily be the *next* problem), but: That code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Declare your variables (such as `line` and `val`) in the appropriate scope. Not declaring them, in loose mode, takes them globals.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't freeze, it throws an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Example:

```js
var data1 = {
        "thing": 1000,
        "last": [
        {"t": 1541239266580, "r": 96, "d": [ 138, 47, 188, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0] },
        {"t": 1541236276321, "r": 97, "d": [ 140, 49, 187, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0] },
        {"t": 1541236161222, "r": 98, "d": [ 140, 49, 187, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0] }
        ]
        };

function iot_json_function(data) {
        var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
        var out = "Thing: " + json_data.thing + "<br>";
        for (line in json_data.last) {
          out += "&nsbp;Time: " + line.t + "<br>";
          out += "&nsbp;Signal Strength: " + line.r + "<br>";
          out += "&nbsp;Data: "
          for (val in line.d) {
             out += val + " ";
          }
          out += "<br>"
        }
 document.getElementById("iot_data_dump").innerHTML = out;
}

try {
  iot_json_function(data1);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
```

That's because you're not passing JSON into `iot_json_function`, you're passing in an object. Since it's not JSON (a **string**), `JSON.stringify` tries to convert it to a string, getting `"[object Object]"`, which isn't valid JSON, so it fails.

JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.